# What is SystemVerilog's equivalent of VHDL's null keyword?

Tags: vhdl, system-verilog

The keyword null is used in VHDL when we want to specify "do nothing". This is mostly used in the state machines in the "others" part as follows:

```
case OPCODE is
    when "001" => TmpData := RegA and RegB;
    when "010" => TmpData := RegA or RegB;
    when "100" => TmpData := not RegA;
    when others => null;
end case;
```

Now my question is, how would this code and the null keyword be written in SystemVerilog?

Comment: I got that piece of code from somewhere else. I am trying to understand the correct concept since I am trying to move from VHDL to SystemVerilog.

Comment: In VHDL the sequence_of_statements in a case statement choice can be empty. The reserved word **null** is used to turn off a driver in a waveform element, represent a null access value, or a sequential null statement which generates no code ("A null statement performs no action"). A semicolon is a separator and case choices are not delimited by semicolons while sequential statements are. `when others => end case;` is semantically equivalent to `when others => null; end case;`. IEEE Std 1800-2017 16.14.1 Assert statement "When no action is needed, a null statement (i.e., ; ) is specified."

Comment: yes I know why null is used in VHDL, I was expecting something similar in SystemVerilog but it clearly does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The `null` keyword has completely different purpose in SystemVerilog from VHDL. In VHDL, `null` represents a placeholder for an empty statement. In SystemVerilog you would simply put a semicolon `;` with nothin preceding it.

```
    3'b001 :  TmpData = RegA & RegB;
    3'b010 :  TmpData = RegA | RegB;
    3'b100 :  TmpData = ~ RegA;
    default:  ;
endcase
```

If this is combinational logic, you probably want a don't care 'x

```
default:  TmpData = 'x;
```